# How to multiply TSQL columns separately by row then SUM the total

Tags: sql, t-sql

**Simple example:**

```
SUM(col1 * col2) as X
```

**This is what I appear to be getting:**

(col1_row1 + col1_row2 ) * (col2_row1 + col2_row2) -- (basically "summing" the columns first then multiplying)

**What I need is this:**

(col1_row1 * col2_row1) + (col1_row2 * col2_row2)

Example: (note that these can be different values)

```
Name | Rate | Cost
------------------
Bob  | .32  | 100
Bob  | .32  | 100
Ted  | .11  | 78
Ted  | .44  | 45

SELECT        
    Name,
    SUM(Rate * Cost) as Value
FROM            
    Blah
Group BY
    Name
```

> Expected: Bob = 64 -- (.32 * 100) + (.32 * 100)

> Actual: Bob = 128 -- (.64 * 200)  incorrect

Posting actual VIEW that I'm working on:

```
SELECT        
    Field.Id as FieldId,
    Field.FieldName,
    Field.FsaId,
    Field.Acres,
    Field.PlanYear,
    Farm.Id as FarmId,
    Grower.Id as GrowerId,
    SUM(FertilizerUses.ApplicationRate * Fertilizer.N) as FertN,
    SUM(Fertilizer.P2o5 * FertilizerUses.ApplicationRate) as Fert2o5,
    SUM(Fertilizer.Mn * FertilizerUses.ApplicationRate) as FertMn,
    SUM(Fertilizer.Mg * FertilizerUses.ApplicationRate) as FertMg,
    SUM(Fertilizer.K2o * FertilizerUses.ApplicationRate) as FertK2o,
    SUM(Fertilizer.Fe * FertilizerUses.ApplicationRate) as FertFe,
    SUM(Fertilizer.S * FertilizerUses.ApplicationRate) as FertS,
    SUM(Fertilizer.B * FertilizerUses.ApplicationRate) as FertB,
    SUM(Fertilizer.Zn * FertilizerUses.ApplicationRate) as FertZn,
    SUM(ManureAnalysis.P2o5 * ManureUses.ManureApplied) as ManP2o5,
    SUM(ManureAnalysis.OrganicN *ManureUses.ManureApplied) as ManOrganicN,
    SUM(ManureAnalysis.Nh4n * ManureUses.ManureApplied) as ManNh4n,
    SUM(ManureAnalysis.N  * ManureUses.ManureApplied) as ManN,
    SUM(ManureAnalysis.K2o * ManureUses.ManureApplied) as ManK2o,
    SUM(ManureAnalysis.Dm * ManureUses.ManureApplied) as ManDm
FROM            
    dbo.Field INNER JOIN
    dbo.Farm ON dbo.Farm.Id = Field.FarmId INNER JOIN
    dbo.Grower ON dbo.Grower.Id = Farm.GrowerId FULL JOIN
    dbo.FertilizerUses ON dbo.Field.Id = dbo.FertilizerUses.FieldId
        AND FertilizerUses.PIversion = Field.PIversion
        AND FertilizerUses.SnapshotVersionId = Field.SnapshotVersionId FULL JOIN
    dbo.Fertilizer ON dbo.FertilizerUses.FertilizerId = dbo.Fertilizer.Id FULL JOIN
    dbo.ManureUses ON dbo.Field.Id = dbo.ManureUses.FieldId 
        AND ManureUses.PIversion = Field.PIversion
        AND ManureUses.SnapshotVersionId = Field.SnapshotVersionId FULL JOIN
    dbo.ManureSource ON dbo.ManureUses.ManureSourceId = dbo.ManureSource.Id FULL JOIN
    dbo.ManureAnalysis ON dbo.ManureUses.ManureAnalysisId = dbo.ManureAnalysis.Id
Group BY
    Field.Id,
    Field.FieldName,
    Field.FsaId,
    Field.Acres,
    Field.PlanYear,
    Farm.Id,
    Grower.Id
```

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: SQL is text, don't post images of text. Someone with as much reputation as yourself should know how to format a post with code.

Comment: FYI, as well, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/).

Comment: Simplified the post is a super basic example with data.   Removed long production VIEW

Comment: can't you simply take the rate out of the sum? you'll then need to add it to your group by clause.

Comment: @Jeremy Then I'll need to add a group by for the calculations, right?

Comment: which calculations? not sure I understand the question

Comment: @Jeremy The rate and cost are different so if I take the rate out, I'd need to add a Group By for the Rate which would cause two rows in the output, right?  Assuming the rates are different which they usually are.  Maybe I'm having a brain fart /shrug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this query in Sql Server 2017:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
  [Name] varchar(100),
  Rate decimal(2,2),
  Cost INT
);
INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT 'Bob',0.32,100 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bob',0.32,100 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ted',0.11,78 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ted',0.44,45
;
SELECT * FROM @Temp;

SELECT 
Name,
SUM(Rate*Cost) AS Value 
FROM @Temp
GROUP BY Name
```

And it gives me the two result sets:
|Name|Rate|Cost|
|--|--|--|
|Bob|0.32|100|
|Bob|0.32|100|
|Ted|0.11|78|
|Ted|0.44|45|

And:
|Name|Value|
|--|--|
|Bob|64.00|
|Ted|28.38|

This seems to be right?

Comment: That's definitely right and what I expected.  My main (a bit more complex) prod query is doing the same but its doubling the results.... hmmmm

Comment: I had my more complex query posted here, I think there's an audit/history?  Can you see my edits on the main post?

Comment: I reposted my actual VIEW if you want to peek at that and see if anything stands out

Comment: If your prod query is doubling the results I guess you have a incorrect join. The next step would be to analyse detail level data and find out why

Comment: Marking this as the answer as Andreas confirmed that the logic i expected is actually right!!  Its my JOIN setup somewhere.